# Django Haystack QuerySet Returns Similar Values Back

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

Hello when I do a Haystack operation with a SOLR backend

SearchQuerySet.filter(categories='sean')

I get results back from both items that are index with both category types of 'Sean' and 'Sean McCully' but not from anything with value of say 'Jason'. Using exact does not elivate this issue. I am using 1.1 version of Haystack and can verify in SOLR that indexes are correct.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is actually part of SOLR and the TOkenizer. Apparently we are using a WhiteSpace Tokenizer that splits up keywords by spaces and creates indexes for both words.